# how to append the values in to the variable and avoid duplicate value?

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I'm working with Ksh shell script, im doing following thing:

```
for provide in $serviceProvideList
do
echo $provide
done
```

which prints strings as follows

```
xoc.memgt.ZMemger
xoc.sv.ZsitionClient
xoc.svc.Zfecycle
xoc.sw.job.temStateHook
xoc.sw.cor.ZBulkOperations
xoc.svc.Zfecycle
xoc.dw.cor.ZMemoryInfo
xoc.memgt.ZMemger
xoc.cot.ZDbug
```

now i have to store that string in to only one variable without duplication of strings.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VAR=$(for i in $serviceProvideList; do echo "$i";done |sort -u)
```

Comment: why do you need the outer `for` in there? seems to work without it. Also, `sort -u` saves you a pipe.

Comment: @Mat: Outer `for` joins list into one line with space as delimiter.

Comment: I understand the intent. I think it's unnecessary though. (not a big deal anyway.)

Comment: @Mat: You're right. Looks like I missed something in `man bash`. :)